# Hover info div background same size as parent div

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation. When the cursor hovers over one of the DIVs in the grid, an info DIV should appear over the top, making the background image darker so that the user can more easily see the text.

Foundation has a default padding for columns. So `position:absolute; width:100%` on the info div background makes it bigger than the Item Div.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns"> 
    <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;...">Tommy...</div>
    <img src=".." style="width:100%; height:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it should look like:
[image: Grid]

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Does the parent (`large-4`) have `position: relative`?

Comment: yes: .columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    float: left; }

Comment: You could remove the `.columns` padding and replace it with margins of the same length. I'm not sure of the limitations of foundation though.

Comment: Why not just remove the padding on the nested div?

Comment: I have solved it out just putting one more div inside. Then info div gets width by it and everything goes ok. Should I delete this question? Thanks

Comment: @Gediminas Have you ever seen my answer below? I posted it 15mins ago.

Comment: @HashemQolami thank you! It may work, but it also works just putting one more div in column, which enlarges to width:100% and has no padding. Thanks again!

Comment: @Gediminas Defintiley leave the question up - someone may have the same problem and your comment may help. In fact, if that's definitley solved it, add it as an answer your own question. You can accept it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have missed one simple thing - putting one more div into columns solves this problem, because new div can be without padding, so it's 100% width, as for parent div, will be ok for info div also. This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns"> 
    <div>
      <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;...">Tommy...</div>
      <img src=".." style="width:100%; height:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a wrapper `<div>` inside the column to contain the `<img>` and the absolutely positioned `<div>`. So that the overlay would respect to the *content-box* of the column rather than the *padding-box*.

```css
.overlay-container { position: relative; display: inline-block; }

.overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;

  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.overlay-container:hover .overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.3/css/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns">

    <div class="overlay-container">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
      <div class="overlay">Overlay text</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```